# problems getting OpenMP 4.0 to run in eclipse (Linux Mint)

Tags: eclipse, gcc, openmp

The error message in eclipse:
[my program]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by [my program])

From other posts I read that a newer version of gcc is required to enable OpenMP 4.0 support (yes, I really need it) so I downloaded and built gcc 6.1 on my Linux Mint machine. gcc --version now spits out 6.1.
After the installation, the warning message at "#pragma omp simd" disappeared, so I assume the installation was successful. But as soon as I insert "#pragma omp parallel for" into my code I get the error message. The code is correct, it runs in Visual Studio (withoutthe simd pragma).
Do I need to install something else?
Is there something else I did wrong?

(If someone knows an easy way to use OpenMP 4.0 on the Windows platform, this would be nice, too (preferably with Visual Studio))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP 4.0 is fully supported since GCC 4.9.1 as shown in the following link. So you may not need to build your own GCC.

http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/

On the other hand, if you build your own GCC, you should try not use the system default version of OpenMP library `libgomp.so` as indicated by the error message. You could use the linking option `-L/path/to/new/libgomp` and `-lgomp` to specify the location of the new library.

According to the above link, MSVC++ supports OpenMP 2.0 only until version 2015.